# Why is QTMovieLoadStateDidChangeNotification not firing?

Tags: cocoa, qtkit

I'm seeing that setting up a notification on QTMovieLoadStateDidChangeNotification has no effect and the target selector never gets called. Am I missing something?

In awakeFromNib:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieLoadStateDidChange:)
                                             name:QTMovieLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

On loading movie:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 url, QTMovieURLAttribute,
 nil];

self.mQTMovie1 = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes
                                               error:&error];
```

Also

```
- (void)movieLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"movieLoadStateDidChange got called");
}
```

Comment: Does simply allocating and initializing the movie change its load state? Do you maybe have to pre-roll it, or play it for the state to change?

Comment: Not according to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is *the* answer but I've encountered this before. The cause in my case was a file whose codec was supported only by a third-party plugin (Flip4Mac in my case).

The load state notification isn't called until the movie finishes after it auto-plays (to nowhere). For long media files, it effectively looks like the notification is never called, since we rarely wait 5 minutes or an hour for a load notification when testing our code. To the user, it looks like the app simply isn't loading the file.

Having the user disable the plugin's auto-play-on-load in System Preferences resolves the issue but unfortunately this one support FAQ I can't get around since users of the app in question frequently use Flip4Mac to support files from common digital voice recorders.

Comment: This is with standard codecs like ProRes and Animation. It was causing issues with setting the movie on a QTMovieLayer since querying the load state was saying it was loaded but it didn't get drawn on screen. In the end I hacked in a 0.2 seconds delay before setting the QTMovieLayer movie and all is good :-)